# Влияние exec на pid процесса

Tags: exec, c++, linux

Если при создании дочернего процесса я получаю его pid, а затем с помощью exec в эту область загружаю некоторое приложение, то это влияет на изменение pid дочернего процесса. Скажите, как в этом случае получить новый pid или может возможно оставить его прежним?

Не подскажете, где ошибка в таком коде:

// main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{ 
 pid_t pid = fork();
 switch(pid)
 {
  case 0: execlp("gnome-terminal", "gnome-terminal", "-e", "/home/user/main2", NULL); break;
  case -1: cout << "error!" << endl; break;
  default: cout << "It's parent's process. PID = " << getpid() << endl << "Child's PID = " << pid << endl << endl; break;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

---

// main2.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 cout << "PID = " << getpid() << endl << "Parent's PID = " << getppid() << endl << endl;
 sleep(10);
 return 0;
}
```

---

Вызываю main. Оттуда создается дочерний, в котором запускается main2. Получаю разные pid.

> Сделано вопросом из ответа в теме [влияние exec на pid процесса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/91517/). @ХэшКод

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не влияет. PID остается прежним. Меняется *программа процесса*.

---

Отформатировал Ваш вопрос (о main2) и отвечаю здесь. PID в main2 новый т.к. **gnome-terminal** перед запуском Вашего main2 (через параметр -e) тоже **делает fork**, а уже в нем exec().

Кстати, чтобы окошко не исчезало, вместо sleep(10) лучше читать stdin, например, вызвать getchar().

С передачей параметров в свой main2 разобрались ?  Может оказаться удобнее запускать в gnome-terminall программу не через -e, а через -x (см. man gnome-terminal).

Comment: Проблема в том, что даже в родительском процессе значение pid не связано получается с дочерним. Нужно как-нибудь связать эти два процесса сигналами. А поскольку теряются значения pid то не представляю как это можно сделать

Comment: Родитель может передать свой PID через параметр (просто сформируйте правильно строку с /home/user/main2 parent-pd). С получением PID main2 в main сложнее. 

Можно сделать pipe и файловый дескриптор pipe[0] тоже передать через параметр. Но (!!!) это сработает **только если gnome-terminal** не закроет перед exec() неизвестные ему (левые с его точки зрения) дескрипторы. Можно только проверить.

Другой способ. main передает в параметрах для main2 **имя файла** в который тот запишет свой PID и потом пошлет сигнал на PID main. Получив сигнал main прочтет из файла PID main2.

Как-то так (места мало)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: IMHO у Вас там еще много заморочек будет (с wait и т.п.)

Comment: Теперь, после редактирования  @ХэшКод, этот ответ и комментарии скорее к [этому](http://hashcode.ru/questions/91523/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-pid) вопросу.

Comment: @avp: перенес тот вопрос сюда.